# what process is executed by the execvp(2) when executable is specified as "/bin/bash"?

Tags: execvp

I know execvp(2) can execute a script in a process. I come across a code of execvp(2) that has no specified executable? It can be compiled and run successfully, but it did nothing.I am not sure what it does. My assume that it just simply open another process but did nothing. But question is, is "/bin/bash" an executable? I think all executable start with prefix, "./", such as "./hello".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  /* exec a shell /bin/bash with no arguments other than its name */
  char *args[] = {"/bin/bash", NULL};
  if (execvp(args[0], args))
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to exec a shell. \n");
    exit(1);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> what process is executed by the execvp(2) when executable is specified as `/bin/bash`?

`/bin/bash` is executed.

> I know execvp(2) can execute a script in a process. I come across a code of execvp(2) that has no specified executable?

That is incorrect.  The code specifies `/bin/bash` as the executable.

> It can be compiled and run successfully, but it did nothing.  I am not sure what it does.

It has NOT done "nothing".

In fact, it replaces the current process with a new shell.  You will now be typing commands to a different shell process to the one that you were previously using.  You can confirm this in various ways; e.g. by looking at the output of `ps -efl` or by running `echo $SHLVL` before and after running your C program.

When you type `exit`, you will return to the previous (parent) shell.

> My assume that it just simply open another process but did nothing.

It only looks that way.  See above.

---

(Your actual question is a red herring based on a misunderstanding / misinterpretation of what the C program is doing.)

> But question is, is "/bin/bash" an executable?

It depends on your system.  But on a typical Linux system it will be.

> I think all executable start with prefix, "./", such as "./hello".

That is incorrect.  The OS decides if a file is an executable based on 1) the file access mode (i.e. whether execute permission is set) and 2) the file type determined by its header.

You can confirm that `bin/bash` is executable by running `ls -l /bin/bash` and `file /bin/bash`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your explanation is very clear. I have one more question. What does the executable, /bin/bash, do? I try to run it on the command line, and it seems nothing happened, except for the value of $SHLVL increment by 1.

Comment: It is the command shell.  It does what the command shell does.  Since you are (probably) already running an instance of "/bin/bash" when you start, you will see very little difference.

Comment: FWIW: another difference you will be able to see is that the command history will appear to have partially reset.  For example, you won't see the command that you used to launch the test program in the child shell's history.  That is because the child shell will have loaded the history from `~/.history` on startup ... and the parent shell only saves its history to `~/.history` when it exits (cleanly).